# cannot rename ESXi server name

Tags: esxi

I am trying to rename my ESXi host, but the edit boxes are grayed out. Am I doing it in the wrong way? I was reading this [article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010821), but no luck..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the setting from "Obtain DNS server address automatically" to "Use the following DNS server address" and then specify the IP address of your DNS server.

After that, you will be able to edit the Name and Domain fields.  Once you change the name, you can change the DNS settings back to automatic if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot ESXi, goto Management Console, and from there you can change host and other settings.